# Modifying columns of weka.core.dataset.Instances object

Tags: python, weka

I'm using python-weka-wrapper3. I have just loaded an arff dataset

```py
kc1_class_arff = arff_loader(DATA_PATH, "/kc1_class.arff")
```

The last column of this dataset is named `NUMDEFECTS` and contains float.

I need this column to be renamed as `DEFECTS` and be turned to integers:

- 1 if NUMDEFECTS != 0
- 0 if NUMDEFECTS = 0

The function arff_loader is the following:

```py
def arff_loader(DATA_PATH, file_name):
    data = loader.load_file(DATA_PATH + file_name)
    data.class_is_last()
    return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a short filter pipeline:

- For renaming the attribute, you can use the [RenameAttribute](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RenameAttribute.html) filter.
- For turning the numeric attribute into an indicator attribute, you can use the [MathExpression](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/MathExpression.html) filter.
- For combining multiple filters, use [MultiFilter](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/MultiFilter.html).

Assuming an input file like:

```
@relation defects

@attribute x1 numeric
@attribute x2 numeric
@attribute NUMDEFECTS numeric

@data
0,1,12.0
1,1,25.1
0,0,5.0
1,0,0.0
-1,0,-10.0
```

You can apply this [python-weka-wrapper3](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3) code:

```py
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
from weka.core.converters import load_any_file
from weka.filters import Filter, MultiFilter

jvm.start()

# load data
data = load_any_file("./defects.arff")

# rename
rename = Filter(classname="weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RenameAttribute",
                options=["-find", "NUMDEFECTS", "-replace", "DEFECTS"])

# float -> indicator
# NB: class attribute must unset for this filter to work!
indicator = Filter(classname="weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.MathExpression",
                   options=["-E", "ifelse(A < 0, 1, ifelse(A > 0, 1, 0))", "-R", "last", "-V"])

multi = MultiFilter()
multi.filters = [rename, indicator]
multi.inputformat(data)
filtered = multi.filter(data)
filtered.relationname = data.relationname
print(filtered)

jvm.stop()
```

And you will get something like this:

```
@relation defects

@attribute x1 numeric
@attribute x2 numeric
@attribute DEFECTS numeric

@data
0,1,1
1,1,1
0,0,1
1,0,0
-1,0,1
```

Once you have obtained the filtered data, you can set the class attribute and return it in your `arff_loader` method.

Comment: I did all what you suggested. The rename filter works, while the indicator doesn't. My output is of this kind now 

`@relation defects  

@attribute x1 numeric  
@attribute x2 numeric  
@attribute DEFECTS numeric  

@data  
0,1,12.0  
1,1,25.1  
0,0,5.0  
1,0,0.0  
-1,0,-10.0`

Comment: Was there a class attribute index set (other than -1)? The MathExpression doesn't touch the class attribute if set.

Comment: Yes I left a class attribute index set. Now it works, thank you! @fracpete

Comment: One more question. How should I change the indicator filter if I want the DEFECTS variable to be true/false values? (false if =0, true if =1)

Comment: MathExpression works only on numeric attributes, so nothing to change here. In order to turn the `DEFECTS` attribute into a nominal one (with labels True/False) you have to extend the filter pipeline: 1. convert the numeric attribute to a nominal one using the [NumericToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToNominal.html) filter; 2. rename the generated labels 0/1 into False/True using the [RenameNominalValues](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RenameNominalValues.html) filter.